# HtmlTextWriter AddAttribute No Quotes In Output

Tags: c#, htmltextwriter

Currently when I use

```
HtmlTextWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlSomething.Class, "Attribute-I-Add")
```

I get the resulting output:

```
<tr class="Attibute-I-Add"></tr>
```

Is there a way to use `AddAttribute` (or something else) and not receive quotes in the output? I know I could use

```
HtmlTextWriter.Write("<tr class=Some-stuff></tr>")
```

... but I was trying to avoid that.

To be clear I am looking for the output `<tr class=Attibute-I-Add></tr>`

Comment: How about replacing quotes after you render it to string?

Comment: I suppose I could do that but at that point I mind as well use HtmlTextWriter.Write. I thought that maybe there was something built in that would do what I want that I didn't know about.